# Linq throwing error. The cast to the value type failed

Tags: c#, linq, join

```
 var result =  from lfx in m_Context.LabFavoriteXrefs
               join lfm in m_Context.LabFavoriteMasterEntries on lfx.lab_favorite_id equals lfm.lab_favorite_id into xm
               from x in xm.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join es in m_Context.ExternalSystems on x.external_system_id equals es.external_system_id into esx
               from e in esx.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new FavoriteOrderTestsDto
               {
                 system_id = lfx.system_id,
                   created_by = lfx.created_by,
                   modified_by = lfx.modified_by,
                   create_timestamp = lfx.create_timestamp,
                   modify_timestamp = lfx.modify_timestamp
               };
        return result;
```

I have attached the error message.

[image]

Comment: One of the properties of PracticeDto that has an int type is trying to be set by a value coming back from the database that is null. Run the query on the database directly and you should be able to see which one. Probably one of your e values as there is an OUTER JOIN to that table.

Comment: Sorry i pasted wrong code. Could you please look at my question once again? @strickt01

Comment: Same concept but with FavoriteOrderTestsDto. Probably e.external_system_id as that is OUTER JOINed

Comment: Change the type of FavoriteOrderTestsDto.external_system_id to int?

Comment: external_system_id is primary key int

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254953/discussion-between-xoxo-and-strickt01).

Comment: Yes but your query may bring it back as null as you are LEFT OUTER JOINing to it. So there may not be an external_system_id (am guessing the culprit here) so your DTO needs to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 left joins in your query which means that the joined data may not be present (`from x in xm.DefaultIfEmpty()` and `from e in esx.DefaultIfEmpty()`), so it will result in `null` returned from database for corresponding columns. You need to change types in `FavoriteOrderTestsDto` to match that, change the corresponding fields/properties (based on names potentially `order_type`, `delete_ind`, `external_system_id` can be source of the issue) to be [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types). For example:

```
public class FavoriteOrderTestsDto
{
    public int? external_system_id {get; set;} 
    // ... the rest
}
```